# Angular - Overriding an attribute doesn't work inside the parent component's html

Tags: angular, typescript

Why when I create a class extends from another and I try to override an attribute doesn't work as expected?

Here's a fictitious example just to simplify the problem:

**Parent class**

**file: gridbase.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../grid/product';
import { ProductService } from '../grid/productservice';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-grid-base',
    templateUrl: './gridbase.component.html'
})
export class GridBaseComponent implements OnInit {
  public rows: Product[] = [];  

    constructor(public productService: ProductService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.productService.getProducts_1().subscribe(
            response => this.rows = response
        )
    }
}
```

**file: gribase.componen.html**

```
<h1>Grid Base</h1>

<p-table [value]="rows" responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
        <tr>
            <td>{{row.code}}</td>
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.category}}</td>
            <td>{{row.quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**file: product.ts**

```
export interface Product {
    id?:string;
    code?:string;
    name?:string;
    description?:string;
    price?:number;
    quantity?:number;
    inventoryStatus?:string;
    category?:string;
    image?:string;
    rating?:number;
}
```

**file: productservice.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from './product';
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getProducts_1(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.http.get<Product[]>('assets/products-example-1.json');
    }
    
    
    getProducts_2(): Observable<Product[]> {
        return this.http.get<Product[]>('assets/products-example-2.json');
    }   
}
```

**file: products-example-1.json**

```
     [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "code": "f230fh0g3",
            "name": "Example 1-1",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "bamboo-watch.jpg",
            "price": 65,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 24,
            "inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK",
            "rating": 5
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "code": "nvklal433",
            "name": "Example 1-2",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "black-watch.jpg",
            "price": 72,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 61,
            "inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK",
            "rating": 4
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "code": "zz21cz3c1",
            "name": "Example 1-3",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "blue-band.jpg",
            "price": 79,
            "category": "Fitness",
            "quantity": 2,
            "inventoryStatus": "LOWSTOCK",
            "rating": 3
        }
    ]
```

**file: products-example-2.json**

```
     [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "code": "f230fh0g3",
            "name": "Example 2-1",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "bamboo-watch.jpg",
            "price": 65,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 24,
            "inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK",
            "rating": 5
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "code": "nvklal433",
            "name": "Example 2-2",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "black-watch.jpg",
            "price": 72,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 61,
            "inventoryStatus": "INSTOCK",
            "rating": 4
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "code": "zz21cz3c1",
            "name": "Example 3-3",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "blue-band.jpg",
            "price": 79,
            "category": "Fitness",
            "quantity": 2,
            "inventoryStatus": "LOWSTOCK",
            "rating": 3
        }
    ]
```

**Child class**

**file: gridchild.component.ts**

```
import { GridBaseComponent } from './../gridbase/gridbase.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../grid/productservice';
import { Product } from '../grid/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gridchild',
  templateUrl: './gridchild.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gridchild.component.css']
})
export class GridChildComponent extends GridBaseComponent implements OnInit {

  override rows: Product[] = [];

  constructor(override productService: ProductService) {
    super(productService);
  }

  override ngOnInit() {
      this.productService.getProducts_2().subscribe(
          response => this.rows = response
      )
  }

}
```

**file: gridchild.component.html**

```
<p>Grid Child works!</p>

<pre>{{rows | json}}</pre>

<app-grid-base></app-grid-base>
```

On this screen gridchild.component.html displays the json correctly, however the line below that calls the parent component does not display the new values but the old/original one (what is in the parent class). How do I make it show the same values as row 2 at this point `(<pre>{{rows | json}}</pre>)`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no data inheritance for components as you are expecting. Typescript inheritance is only at compile time and only sub classes can overwrite parent's behavior, not the other way around.

To achieve your desired result you may want want to add rows as @Input variable to the component

Comment: I had already tried to add "@Input()" in the line "public rows: Product[] = [];" of the "GridBaseComponent" class, but it didn't work.
Can you show the code how it would look then?

Comment: In addition to that , you will have to remove ngOnInit from the super class

Comment: I did that and that didn't work either.